# Angularjs error Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory, angular-controller

I get the error

> Unknown provider: $userProvider <- $user"

With following code:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.factory("user", function($scope, $http) {
   var usr = {};
   usr.getAllLists = function(){
       return "test";
   }
   return usr;  
});

cart.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$http", "$user", 
    function ($scope, $http, user){

        $scope.initialize = function(){
            $scope.lists = user.getAllLists();
        }

    }
]);
```

Do you see the mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming cart is having dependency on app module.

```
cart.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$http", "user", 
    function ($scope, $http, user){

        $scope.initialize = function(){
            $scope.lists = user.getAllLists();
        }
    }
```

It has to be user and not `$user`.

Also, in factory, in place of `$scope`, use `$rootScope`.

Comment: ty for your answer. I changed that before too but i without $ i get: "Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- user". Do you know what is going on now?

Comment: cart module is different, it must be having dependency on app?

Comment: I changed $scope in factory to $rootScope. Now it works. Does a controller has his own scope?

Comment: You made the right change - even I missed on that. Every controller has his own scope whereas services and factories can only access the rootScope

Comment: Do you have any other questions/queries?